# Create a file containing a string and no CR or LF in a batch script

Tags: scripting, batch-file

I am trying to generate sha256 hash of a string in a batch script.

For this purpose I found sha256sum.exe ([link](http://blog.nfllab.com/archives/152-Win32-native-md5sum,-sha1sum,-sha256sum-etc..html)) 
this application accepts file arguments only.

Thus I need to create a file with the string, and no trailing space nor CR or LF.

in my batch script I did:

```
echo.|set /P =%var%>temp.txt
sha256sum temp.txt > temp2.txt
```

I used the first line to remove CR & LF however in temp.txt file I see a single trailing space char, which is then used by sha256sum.exe.

I am trying to get rid of that trailing space character at the end of the first line of the text file.

I am a linux user and I wasn't expecting such a simple thing to be a problem.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can either use GnuWin32 or UnxUtils and then use : `rev | cut -b 1- | rev` or `sed "s/.$//"` for example. Batch scripting is very painful if you cannot use those tools. Removing TRAILING whitespace, not all whitespace, is really difficult. There isn't even a builtin function to get the length of the contents of a variable.

Comment: Currently I am trying to do this without another tool if possible. In this case, it is also valid to remove all whitespace because the string doesn't contain any space other than the one at the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplest thing would be to replace all whitespace;

```
set h=0x0C29A1BCD3DC8425712A0107B6693361CCBBABAC 
echo."%h%"
set h=%h: =%
echo."%h%"

>> "0x0C29A1BCD3DC8425712A0107B6693361CCBBABAC "
>> "0x0C29A1BCD3DC8425712A0107B6693361CCBBABAC"
```

**Edit**

Sorry, I didnt realise the extra space was in the written value, how about

```
@echo off
set var=hashme
for %%a in (%var%) do (
echo/|set /p ="%%a"
)>temp.txt

FOR /F "tokens=1" %%i in ('sha1sum temp.txt') do SET var=%%i 
echo "%var:~0,-1%"
```

I downloaded that sha1sum.exe and for `"hashme"` the output is correct;

```
"fb78992e561929a6967d5328f49413fa99048d06"
```

Comment: can I get help about how can I join this command with the first line in my code above, which I use to remove CR LF?

Comment: I should clarify that I see the trailing space at the end of the line in tmp.txt, not in tmp2.txt. If I use your solution it doesn't work because temp.txt has the space in it and sha256sum produces the wrong result.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
set /p =%var%>temp.txt <NUL
```

instead of:

```
echo.|set /P =%var%>temp.txt
```